# Использование кавычек во фразах про голоса "за" и "против"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Мне кажется правильным, чтобы слова "за" и "против" для всех служебных сообщений сайта *Stack Overflow на русском*, где под этими словами подразумевается голос "за" и "против" соответственно, обрамлялись выбранными на сайте кавычками-ёлочками `«` и `»`. Примеры:

Ёлочки нужны:

- > Показать суммарное кол-во голосов «за» и «против»

Ёлочки не нужны:

- > Голосовать за закрытие вопроса

Сейчас во многих местах наблюдается текст без кавычек там, где, как мне кажется, они должны быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил ёлочки в соответствующих строках. Если кто-то заметит отсутствие или другие проблемы с ними - просьба сообщать в комментариях к этому сообщению или в чате.

---

Обновление будет доступно после подгрузки строк из transifex и последующей сборки сайта.