# Описание знака "Спортивное поведение"

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, привилегии

На странице  привилегии ["Голосовать За"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)
, указано следующее описание данного знака:

> Участник проголосовал «за» 100 конкурсных ответов.

А находясь в профиле, открывая модальное окно с доступными знаками, мы видим следующее описание:

> 100 раз проголосовать «за» другие ответы на вопросы, где ваш ответ имеет положительный рейтинг.

Это же описание мы видим на странице [Знаки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

Полагаю, описание на странице привелегии "Голосовать За" некорректное и его стоит исправить.

Comment: Это к Николасу.

Comment: @Suvitruf некоторые рекомендуют за такие переводы руки отрывать :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большое спасибо! Внес изменения, чуть-чуть поменяв под контекст.

Comment: Форматирование какое-то разнообразное по знакам в конце страницы. Надо бы наверное весь текст на новую строку переносить.

Comment: @älёxölüt Спасибо за замечание, поправил!

Comment: там начиная от "глас народа" проблемы с формулировками

Comment: @älёxölüt  Пожалуйста, опишите в вопросе, что надо поправить.

Comment: Отдельный вопрос замутить? В принципе суть описана в [уже существующем вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4062/176217).