# Автоперевод содержимого Stack Overflow. Что вы об этом думаете?

Tags: обсуждение, перевод-содержимого

Последнее время начал замечать, уверен, не я один, все больше сайтов с автопереводом содержимого Stack Overflow на английском в поисковой выдаче. Если раньше в поисковой выдаче на русском языке были ссылки на разнообразные сайты, то теперь автопереводы  забили всю выдачу, выдавив оттуда реальный опыт русскоязычных разработчиков, который накапливался годами.

[На Stack Overflow на русском мы блокируем ссылки на подобные сайты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7104/6), но чувствуется, что проблема куда больше. Причем, ситуация доставляет фрустрацию не только нам. К примеру, люди [разрабатывают расширения](https://github.com/Taraflex/Back2stackoverflow), которые автоматически перенаправляют их с сайта автопереводов на Stack Overflow на английском.

**Коллеги, подскажите, пожалуйста, что лично вы думаете о таких сайтах? Почему? Что вы предлагаете с ними делать?**

Соглашусь, нет смысла обсуждать какие–то сторонние проекты в рамках нашей Меты. С другой стороны, случай исключительный по двум причинам:

- Страдает все русскоязычное сообщество (и не только русскоязычное, подобные сайты появляются на многих языках).
- Подобные сайты — наш [антипод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). Хотя содержимое этих сайтов изначально заимствовано со Stack Overflow на английском, они олицетворяют собой то, от чего мы хотели уйти, запуская наш сайт — [апатию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F), посредственное отношение к программированию, к сообществу.

Очень хочется услышать ваши мысли на эту тему и вместе предпринять шаги по улучшению базы знаний по программировани на русском языке.

Comment: _не можешь победить - возглавь_ :)

Comment: Лично меня такие сайты очень раздражают, постоянно выдает qaru, с его убогим переводом. Так мало того, что перевод ужасен, так еще и из-за adblock текст ответа отражается по горизонтали. Единственное, что хочется сделать на таких сайтах - это нажать "Источник" и закрыть вкладку. P.S. Уже несколько раз искал в настройках поисковой системы, как удалить сайт из поисковой выдачи - не нашел

Comment: @wcobalt  Не моги бы вы написать ваш отзыв в виде ответа? П.С. используйте «запрос -сайт».

Comment: Гм, о каких сайтах с автопереводом речь? Не попадались такие. Имхо, проблема раздута. Обычно я ищу документация и т. п. на английском. Но, впрочем, припоминаю, когда ищу на русском, изредка попадаются такие сайты, но это когда я упорно терзаю поисковик, составляя хитроумные запросы с кучей фильтров. То есть заведомо ничего достойного нет, вот и появляется такое в выдаче.

Comment: Основная проблема в том, что мы не в первых строках выдачи поисковика (я смотрел yandex). Далее уже не важно, автоперевод впереди нас или что-то другое. Вот эту проблему и надо решать (к сожалению, я не специалист в продвижении сайтов)

Comment: @avp Спасибо за отзыв! Проблема с Яндексом известная, но как решить — не понятно. Если откинуть SEO–вопросы, подскажите, как вы думает, что бы помогло нам эффективней создавать базу знаний, чтобы выбить автопереводы из поиска хотя бы по базовым вопросам? П.С. Будучи студентом, я помню как изучал большинство аспектов по статьям rsdn'а. Как только представлю, что  сегодняшние студенты изучают программирование по сгенерированным текстам, то так грустно становится.

Comment: Nicolas, я по прежнему считаю, что нам нужен как раз отказ от концепции *базы знаний*.  Нужно оперативное решение конкретных задач в режиме  живого, доброжелательного диалога. Для людей весьма важно общение с теми, кого они считаю авторитетными, возможность переспросить и узнать мнение конкретного человека.

Comment: @avp Про общение с авторитетным специалистом я с вами согласен. Правда, в базу знаний я верю не меньше. Подскажите, как вы себе подобное в рамках SO? Я пытался реализовать подобное в чатах и «диалога о работе» на Мете.

Comment: Скорее всего рейтинг (пейдж ранк у гугла) низкий потому что у автопереводов стоят ссылки на SO, а мы слишком мелкие по сравнению с ним, настолко что одни лишь ссылки на SO выводят автопереводы выше нас. Что делать - расти нужно в глазах поисковиков.

Comment: @wcobalt я пользуюсь в Chrome расширением https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef для блокировки в поисковой выдачи определённых доменов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, реальные изменения в рамках SO возможны только при изменении как дизайна (естественно и кода), так и идеологии. Мне видится 2 уровня student/profi, (перемещение участников SO и вопросов между ними в принципе возможно). Избранные вопросы из каждого помещаются в базу знаний (вероятно это должно отдельно стимулироваться), которая помимо меток структурирована по темам. Желательна в самом деле хорошая поисковая система по базе. С каждым вопросом на той же странице существует чат для свободного обсуждения (это убирает проблему обсуждения в комментариях). Технически что-то такое.

Comment: Questions tagged [sql-server] × 247111; Вопросы с меткой [sql-server] × 2,050 вопросов. При этом половина, а может и больше русскоязычных вопросов - это вопросы уровня студента-первокурсника. А вы тут переводы-шмелеводы обсуждаете. Если вдруг у меня возникает вопрос, я уже давным давно даже не пытаюсь найти ответ в русском интернете - только время тратить.

Comment: Достаточно немного подтянуть английский и проблема с ссылками на переводы отпадает сама собой. Собственно это и есть причина того, почему в русскоязычном СО все так грустно ).

Comment: @kulikovman На мой взгляд, от того, что я выучу английски ссылок на автоперевод в поисковой выдаче меньше не станет (к слову, Google показывает такие сайты для меня выше SOen даже если я ищу на английском). Вопрос же об этом. Подскажите, как бы вы его решили?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, мне кажется вы преувеличиваете. Ни разу не видел сайты с переводом при поиске на английском, так же использую google. Попробуйте дать пример такого запроса, я проверю.

Comment: @kulikovman: могу ещё одну data point от себя добавить: даже при поиске по английским словам, в выводе сайты на русском могут быть

Comment: Я английский знаю и ищу ответы на нем. Но и авто-перевод бывает не полохим. Уровень на школьном + длительная работа с англоязычными заказчиками(я учился на них). Авто-переводу однозначно быть, но кнопочкой англоязычном на сайте, с правильным тегом canonical и hreflang.

Comment: И с бонусами реврайтерам, вот будет круто :) А пока приходится пользоватся английским т.к. сообщество больше, и не только SO интересен.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky в настройках браузера поставьте английский выше, поисковик это учитывает. Это к вопросу не относится, но даже локаль у меня английская, так привычнее, и на askubuntu помогает отвечать на вопросы.

Comment: @LeonidMew: это не работает (вывод qaru  выше ссылок на [en]SO), по крайней мере для комбинации  google + chrome.

Comment: @wcobalt посмотрите решения [здесь](https://toster.ru/q/556616) (сам не проверял)

Comment: @Alex спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: Добавлю в копилку и свой "горький" опыт.     
Мне уже поздно учить английский, (из-за старости), поэтому использую [вот этот переводчик](https://quest-app.appspot.com/), остальное "догоняю" по смыслу... Прелесть этого переводчика в разнообразии автопереводов.

Answer (score 17):

Пока лицензия допускает использовать сообщения в каком бы то ни было виде, сохраняя ссылку на оригинальное расположение сообщения и автора, такие сообщения будут доступны в поисковиках. Поэтому нужно либо изменять лицензию, но это вряд ли произойдёт, а если и произойдёт, доказать способ перевода - автоматически или в ручном режиме он был сделан, не представляется возможным. Кто-то будет ругать ручной перевод, так как считает его искажённым и некачественным, а кто-то может и похвалить автоматизированный (технологии не стоят на месте).

Очевидное решение, хоть и озвученное в шуточной форме в [комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8267/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-stack-overflow-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5#comment34104_8267) под вопросом - добавлять автоматические переводы с enSO, как наиболее объёмного сайта на руСО и другие локализованные сайты. Помечать такие вопросы плашкой, что перевод был сделан автоматически (так уже делают другие сайты, например, MSDN и cppreference.com) и предлагать участникам улучшить такой перевод. Разумеется, стоит как-то доработать механизм поощрения таких правок, чтобы получать за них репутацию, иначе такими переводами мало кто будет заниматься.

Comment: Спасибо, интересное замечание! Как вы считаете, можно ли в текущей ситуации обойтись без автоматического перевода?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky можно. Если не заморачиваться наличием ссылок на сайты автопереводов с гугла. Ну, есть и есть. Создавать качественный и нужный контент на русском, тогда не будет надобности его (авто)переводить. Только если на другие языки, но это уже будет проблемой других сообществ. А вообще, я слышал, что на SO принято голосовать вместо выражения благодарности в комментариях.

Comment: Не могли бы вы раскрыть идею автопереводов с правкой сообществом подробнее (как я понимаю, вы понимаете какова механика процесса)? Как мне кажется, на первый взгляд, это путь в некуда. (1) В случае обычного перевода и правки автоматического перевода на выходе будет содержимое совершенно разного качества, так как человек переводит смысл, а машина слова. (2) Крутость SO в том, что это не просто сайт с бесплатным содержимым, сообщество взаимной помощи стоящее за содержимым на порядки важнее. Если бы это было не так, новых вопросов не появлялось бы.

Comment: (3) У содержимого сайта есть жизненный цикл и если он заканчивается (технология меняется), содержимое будет изменено. Мне все время приходят уведомления о комментариях в очень старых вопросах. Кто–то просит уточнения, кто–то рассказывает, что появилось обновления. В результате, я могу изменить свой ответ. Если переводчик — случайный человек, он вряд ли будет являться носителем знаний и не сможет среагировать. Есть еще много мыслей, почему автоматические — зло. Подскажите, что вы думаете?

Comment: Еще один хороший пример — Википедия. Там нет автопереводов, на сколько я понимаю. Если содержимое переводится, то людьми. Обратите внимание на страницу «[сообщество](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)». На ней есть раздел «[перевод недели](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Translation_of_the_week/ru)» внизу страницы. Это, скорее, ближе к переводу канонических вопросов, чем автопереводу всего сайта с последующей правкой.

Comment: Не надо автопереводы - они искажают смысл текста, порой до противоположного! И уж тем более не надо делать как сделано в MSDN, где даже кнопки "перейти на англоязычную версию" нет!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky детали реализации - это детали, их можно и имеет смысл обсуждать, когда и если будет принято общее решение о необходимости добавления нового функционала. Википедия более популярна, чем SO и тем более, чем SO на русском, и, как я понимаю, она не страдает от проблем наличия сайтов автопереводов в поисковой выдаче. Почему? Вероятно объём не тот, или ещё какие-то причины (может и лицензия), которые владельцам сайтов автопереводов не подходят. Может и с поисковиками у Википедии иные отношения, чем с SO.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я озвучил возможный подход решения проблемы поставленной в вопросе. Я не считаю, что он идеален и вообще нужен. Но коли уж КМ просит обсуждения... Решение ничего не делать - тоже решение. Но его раскрыть в подробностях сложнее :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вообще то кнопка есть, и на MSDN, и на Microsoft Docs ("Прочитать на английском" в верхней панели).

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight она оставляет в адресной строке ссылку на кривой перевод

Comment: @PavelMayorov Тогда выбор языка в левом нижнем углу.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight давайте ещё какой-нибудь сайт обсудим? :)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ахренеть куда запрятали...

Comment: Согласен с автором, но только не автоматический перевод!

Answer (score 11):

Насколько я помню многократное обсуждение этого вопроса в чате с коммьюнити менеджером -- текущий движок stackoverflow крайне плохо заточен под русскоязычные поисковые машины.

И контент stackoverflow проигрывает SEO-конторам, потому что управляющая компания на протяжении многих лет не может (не хочет?) выделить ресурсы на допиливание движка под русскоязычные конторы.

Вероятно, перед тем, как включаться в гонку за автоматизированный перевод следовало навести порядок с движком. Я приводил примеры в чате когда мой русский ручной (!) перевод вопроса с основного stackoverflow отсутствовал в поисковой выдаче: ru.stackoverflow.com там отсутствовал как класс, зато через некоторое время появлялись клоны на других сайтах.

Поэтому давайте уточним один важный момент: если просто будет сделан автоматический перевод содержимого en so на ru so -- то какие вообще гарантии, что этот контент появится в поисковиках? Я не говорю уже о том, что он появится выше сайтов, которые сейчас это делают -- это вообще из области фантастики. Я приводил примеры запросов, когда so отсутствует в выдаче, даже при наличии оригинального контента.

И вот только после этого можно будет говорить о том, чтобы делать автоматический перевод контента.

На мой взгляд, как человека умеющего в английский -- нужно для локализованных сообществ делать настройку, в которой пользователь мог бы отключать автоперевод и видеть оригинальный вопрос. Также была бы хороша настройка режима поиска - только по ru so или по ru so + en so, потому что я часто в комментариях к вопросам даю ссылку на en so, так как знаю, что там ответ есть.
Третья фича, которая мне кажется уместной -- это перевод в стиле как в MSDN: можно навести мышкой на переведённое предложение и увидеть оригинальный текст. Иногда, мгм, бывают нюансы и неточности автоперевода.

Думаю, что подобные фичи по настройке отображения автоперевода - это второе требование, которое нужно будет реализовывать в обязательном порядке. Без него лично у меня ru so будет мало чем отличаться от мусорных сайтов -- но я вполне верю, что найдутся люди, которым не принципиально видеть автоперевод, а не исходный текст.

Comment: Возможно, вопрос поставлен не корректно. Его основная мысль в том, что автоперевод — вроде бы, дело не очень полезное. Сейчас Stack Overflow на русском — это реальные знания сообщества, стоящего позади содержимого. Я лично верю в сообщество куда больше, чем в алгоритмы автоматического перевода. Надеюсь, до автопереводов на нашем сайте дело никогда не дойдет.

Comment: Подскажите, что бы вы предложили сделать (и почему), если предположить, что на SO автопереводов не будет никогда, а исправить ситуацию мы все-таки прям очень-очень хотим?

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, что именно в движке не допилено?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Нужно провести SEO-аудит и узнать, что не так с движком. Мы тут не специалисты в этой шаманской дисциплине, поэтому нужно просто выбрать тех шаманов, у которых "получается".

Comment: Спасибо! Мне кажется, нам необходимо искать решение другого характера.

Answer (score 8):

## Помогают ли сайты-автопереводы миссии Stack Overflow?

Основной интерфейс ru.SO сайта, [источники траффика — это
поисковики](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources):
человек делает запрос по имеющейся проблеме и переходит по ссылкам, с
возможными решениями.

По количеству вопросов, [[en]SO на порядок/два больше
ru.SO](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions), поэтому ожидаемо,
что сайты-автопереводы могут лучшее совпадение для ключевых слов в
запросе предоставлять (выбор больше) и забивать весь вывод поисковиков
(SERP), если алгоритмы поисковиков не штрафуют такие сайты. Раньше
даже клоны самого [en]SO доминировали SERP — это говорит, насколько
плохо SO для поисковиков был оптимизирован (субъективно сейчас меньше
проблем с SEO).

Если человек уже знает английский, то появление сайтов-автопереводов в
SERP может раздражать, но *если люди, могут найти решение через
сайты-автопереводы, тогда такие сайты можно приветствовать ([служит
миссии SO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044))*. В
качестве анекдота, иногда (крайне редко) я нахожу решения на языках,
которых не знаю. В таких случаях, наличие автоперевода в браузере
лучше полного отсутствия решения. Пример: содержимое статьи [«...Как
избавиться от коллеги, пишущего на
Питоне»](https://lameiro.wordpress.com/2010/07/18/deixando-o-interpretador-python-maluco/)
принесло пользу в том числе благодаря наличию функции автоперевода в
браузере ([контекст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571490/23044)).

Интересно, многие ли знают, сам ru.SO не является сайтом-автопереводом
[en]SO?

Эксперименты показывают, что при наличии ответа на ru.SO, можно найти
решение по соответствующим ключевым словам в поисковиках.

### Что делать?

- работать на SEO, если есть возможность
- продолжать отвечать на вопросы и пополнять копилку решений
- в рекламе ru.SO подчёркивать, что ответы живыми людьми (в основном) создаются

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Все таки, на мой взгляд, автопереводы это больше плохо, чем хорошо, так как они разрушают сообщество. Когда кто–то получает хороший развернутый ответ на сайте от вас, MaxU, VladD и многих других участников, это невероятно мотивирует. Сообщество реальных знатоков важно. С другой стороны, переводчик сам по себе, конечно дело здоровское :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky факты не изменятся: поисковики—основной источник траффика и [en]SO больше в 10-100 раз ru.SO, поэтому пытаться избавиться от [en]SO содержимого для русскоязычных запросов, в пустую. Выбор только в том либо сам SO будет авто-переводы предоставлять или третьи сайты.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каким виде, на ваш взгляд, переводы возможны в рамках модели SO?

Comment: _что ответы живыми людьми (в основном) создаются_ - эм, а если примеры с неживыми?

Comment: @Grundy: обсуждаемая тема: "Автоперевод содержимого..." Есть целые сайты, которые ботами пополняются. На SO также боты есть (и полезные и вредные). Из полезных: всякие боты-голосовалки в помощь модераторам, удаление приветствий итд. Из вредных:  спам (давно не встречался). Видел примеры копипаста с [en]SO с (то что выглядит как) автопереводом (это редко, чаще просто копирование с отсутствием понимания, но это отдельная тема).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky перевод -- это инструмент, чтобы человеку помочь решение его задачи
найти. То есть это проблема поисковиков, но им можно помочь (что нужно
поисковику, чтобы он по русским ключевым словам, мог ответы на
английском находить?). Когда ответ на английском найден, то
авто-перевод его -- это уже проблема браузера. Тут много деталей --
кому-то вообще не надо переводить (знаний достаточно, чтобы как есть
ответ был бы полезен), кому-то нужно подсказать/сделать более явной
возможность автоперевода (в интерфейсе, ссылкой/сообщением)...

Comment: ... В
каких-то случаях, можно направить на ru.SO, чтобы вопрос задали, если
первые два варианта не помогли.

Comment: «ru.SO сайта» звучит!

Comment: _если люди, могут найти решение через сайты-автопереводы_  - но эти люди ведь могут в перевести en.SO и в браузере

Comment: @RealKEK сперва поисковик должен вернуть ссылку на SO вопрос, прежде чем его переводить можно. И верно, я уже  явно выше упомянул, что браузер для перевода может быть использован некоторыми людьми.

Answer (score 4):

Мое мнение - это проблемы поисковиков. Действительно автопереводы в поиске раздражают и разрадражение появляется по отношению к поисковику, а не к нам, мы то тут причем. Нам нужно еще раз напомнить поисковику о его некачественной работе. То есть кроме индексации теперь еще и с рейтингом проблемы. Чего делать не нужно, так это целенаправленно боротся с этим.

Нам нужно повышать свое влияние и репутацию высоким качеством материалов, привлечением квалифицированных участников. Это сложно они должны не просто прийти, а остаться.

Теперь по-поводу, позиции в поисковой выдаче. Место в выдаче напрямую зависит от рейтинга сайта и у Гугла, и у Яндекса. Алгоритм расчета рейтинга это коммерческая тайна поисковика. Но известно, что играют роль ссылки, тут простая эвристика - если на тебя много хороших сайтов ссылаются, то и ты видимо хороший, поэтому рейтинг пожно повыше сделать. Понятно что в действительности все сложней многократно: скорее всего рейтингов несколько, учитывается наверно контекст ссылок, их возраст... накрутить тут можно очень много. Я это все к тому, что нам стоит обратить внимание на то чтобы на нас по-больше ссылались. Тогда рейтинг вырастет.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Очень здравое замечание. Я тоже считаю, что необходимо в первую очередь улучшать качество вопросов и ответов в нашей базе знаний. И, конечно, вовлекать коллег в учатие в профессиональном сообществе.

Comment: Рейтинг ничего не даст, когда искомой информации на сайте просто нет, а на сайте автопереводов она есть, так как вопрос с enSO ещё не приехал на руСО. А вот когда информация на сайте есть, то это уже другая ситуация, но тоже я бы не назвал её проблемой поисковиков. Это проблема недостаточной раскрутки руСО.

Comment: @älёxölüt Подскажите, что вы подразумеваете под «раскруткой»?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky продвижение в поисковой выдаче наверх.

Comment: Согласен что целенаправленно бороться с этим не нужно, пустая трата своих сил и времени. А вот чем стоит заняться это улучшением сайта, и атмосферы внутри.

Comment: Я создал несколько сайтов, ни на один из них нет внешних ссылок, но они находятся всегда на первых позициях выдачи (по конкретному городу Симферополь), так как я хорошо продумал сео-наполнение, правильно их зарегистрировал, правильно написал html-код. При чем здесь сколько сайтов ссылаются? Сайты с автопереводом, о которых вы говорите, поднялись резко вверх ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО из-за рекламного контента, из которого они на 60-80 % состоят. Это бизнес, не более. Поэтому как гугл, так и яндекс автоматически поднимают их вверх так как за их счет получают прибыль

Answer (score 3):

Почитал ответы и комментарии. Пожалуй, выскажусь.

Я уже как-то говорил, что SO сделал гнилое дело, убив многие русскоязычные программерские форумы. Конечно, он хорош именно как сайт типа вопрос-ответ, даже прекрасен. Но суть в том, что он не является платформой для общения, какими были другие программерские форумы. На них всегда были флудилки, разделы юмора, жизни, политики и многие другие.

Как можно кардинально решить проблему? Посмотрим на англоязычные сайты SO: тысячи их! Политика, религия, наука, аниме... Сделайте аналогичные сайты на русском и люди потянутся к вам. **Аудитория увеличится**, возрастёт **количество** потенциальных авторов хороших **ответов**, **поисковая выдача увеличится**.

---

В других темах неоднократно отмечалось, что разработчики SO забили на неанглоязычные версии. В частности, им наплевать на кривой внешний вид, когда более длинные слова и фразы не лезут в размеры.

Поэтому давайте признаем, что эти русские и другие версии были созданы с одной целью: оттянуть на себя часть людей с других программерских форумов (ага, убить их), но вовсе не с целью предоставления качественного контента, бла-бла-бла... Просто бизнес.

Comment: Как создание русскоязычных "Политика.SO", "Музыка.SO", "Спорт.SO", "Масоны.SO" увеличит поисковую выдачу на вопросы "Как найти минимальный нечетный элемент в массиве"?

Comment: @АндрейNOP я думаю, это просто крик души. И здесь, конечно, вряд ли кто-то будет возражать, что хорошо было бы иметь все эти разнообразные сайты. Но к обозначенной в вопросе проблеме ответ в текущем виде отношения не имеет.

Comment: Я выделил главное.

Comment: Лично мне программерские форумы не жаль совершенно. Как правило все скатываются в неконтролируемый поток сознания и сравнение ЧСВ. Задаются уйма вопросов, на которые в лучшем случае RTFM или копипаст неправильных/устаревших ответов с аналогичных форумов. Реальной пользы - ноль

Answer (score 3):

Выскажу пожалуй своё скромное мнение (более того я ранее уже обсуждал подобные сайты на мете).

## Оптимизация SO для поисковых систем.

Здесь очень много обсуждается движок незаточенный под SEO-оптимизацию именно русского сегмента.
Не могу понять как нужно допиливать движок именно для русского сегмента и чем поисковая оптимизация на русском языке отличается от поисковой оптимизации на английском (*спойлер: ничем*)

**Суть поисковой оптимизации - работа над контентом.**

Поисковик оценивает тот сайт выше, чей контент больше подходит к конкретному поисковому запросу. Работа SEO-оптимизатора сводится к написанию контента, как можно более подходящего выбранному поисковому запросу, проставлению мета-тегов, ссылок и к семантической разметке.

Семантическая разметка на ruSO имеется:
используется https://schema.org/Question

С точки зрения работы над контентом мы имеем все и ничего.

Любой член сообщества может отредактировать всё что угодно.
Как вопрос - так и ответ, как текст - так и заголовок.
Любая целенаправленная работа по оптимизации пользовательского контента - бессмысленна.
В любом случае он постоянно изменяется и Вы никак не можете на это повлиять.
Более того, поисковая оптимизация практически всегда проводится с ухудшением качества контента, в угоду более близкому сходству с ключевыми словами.
Поэтому данная работа не просто бессмыслена но и неприемлема.
Более того наши конкуренты этого также не делают (Да и как это сделать с таким количеством контента?).

Мы можем только создавать новый контент - и все.
Как бы это ни было печально.

**Может всё-таки можно что-то сделать с движком SO для SEO-оптимизации?..**

<strike>Единственная идея: автоматический вынос в тег `<title></title>` названия меток или хотя бы названия самой популярной метки вопроса.

Данная очень незначительная правка может принести несоизмеримый профит.</strike>(имеется)

> **UPD:** Вторая идея - автоматическая регистрация оригинального контента в Яндекс.Вебмастер
>   API Яндекс.Вебмастер:
>   https://tech.yandex.ru/webmaster/doc/dg/reference/host-original-texts-post-docpage/

## Почему ruSO по многим запросам в поиске ниже сайтов-конкурентов?..

Для этого я предлагаю сравнить ruSO и сайт конкурент(на примере qaru)

- Какая-либо специальная сео-оптимизация на нём не производилась. 
  Тайтлы и заголовки эквивалентны, за исключением меток.
- Метка в тайтле присутствует (как и на ruSO).
- Семантическая разметка присутствует (как и на ruSO).
- Перелинковка на qaru, хуже чем на ruSO (у нас есть связанные и похожие вопросы, а у них нет)

То есть всё ровно тоже самое, что и на ruSO и хуже.

Возникает, закономерный вопрос: а почему тогда он выше в поисковой выдаче?

Для этого предлагаю перейти в гугл и оценить количество страниц двух этих сайтов находящихся на данный момент в индексе.

В индексе google.com сейчас находится:

- 405 000 страниц `ru.stackoverflow.com`
- 2 280 000 страниц `qaru.site` :

И вот Вам ответ: у них банально больше контента (в 5 раз больше страниц, и под каждым вопросом в среднем больше ответов, а значит вес каждой страницы больше).

И тут уже стоит призадуматься о том, как увеличить количество страниц.

К своему стыду и позору я не знаю всех аспектов работы нашего ресурса

В частности помню(могу ошибаться), что какие-то вопросы раньше, если на них не отвечают в течении какого-бы то ни было длительного времени(например год) то ли закрывались, то ли удалялись Духом Сообщества.(Не швыряйте в меня тапками если это не так)

<strike>Но если это действительно так, то вполне возможно такие стратегии можно пересмотреть в сторону сохранения контента и его актуализации.</strike> ([вопрос снят](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2))

## Итого:

Мы можем:

- работать над контентом
- <strike>пересмотреть стратегии по удалению некоторых вопросов</strike>  ([вопрос снят](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2))
- автоматическая регистрация оригинального контента
- <strike>метки в тайтле</strike>(*имеется*)

---

**UPD:**

Отправил вопрос сотрудникам Яндекса относительно их политики в данном вопросе.
 Полученный ответ(если он будет) приложу к данному посту.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Кмк мне кажется, смотреть в сторону ухудшения содержимого сайта (не удалять заброшенные вопросы) не стоит. А вот улучшать уже имеющиеся вопросы или писать новые хорошие развернутые — дело крайне нужное!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, в перспективе(как мне кажется) данные сайты будут пессимизированы в выдаче. Во всяком случае публичная политика поисковиком нацелена на поддержку создателей оригинального контента и у поисковиков есть инструменты для регистрации оригинального контента(кстати еще одна идея для движка - автоматическая регистрация страниц в данных инструментах). А вопрос пессимизации конкурентов с автопереводами вопрос времени.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, относительно удаления... как мне кажется, автоматически невозможно определять качество вопроса. Может стоит создать отдельную очередь, в которую и будут попадать устаревшие вопросы и там уже участники будут решать, стоит ли данный вопрос отправлять на покой или он просто сложный и затеряный и его нужно реанимировать. Опять же повторюсь, что я не курсе всех алгоритмов и статистики...может под нож идут и впрямь только некачественные вопросы, однако, с первого взгляда кажется, что там может потеряться и немало хороших вопросов, на которые сообщество просто не успело ответить

Comment: Движок удаляет *заброшенные вопросы* – на сколько помню, [это вопросы без ответа с голосом против](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392/6). Про пессимизацию звучит интересно, увидим со временем. С другой стороны, хочется активно нести в массы идею свободных знаний и показывать на личном примере, что получить ответ на русском языке на вопрос по программированию не просто возможно, но и довольно легко, а сам ответ будет прекрасным. Было бы очень здорово, если бы мы смогли подумать как этого добиться вместе.

Comment: Метка в заголовок и на руСО выносится. См. основной сайт, не Мету!

Comment: @älёxölüt, спасибо. Поправлю.

Comment: отослал сотрудникам Яндекса вопрос по их политике, относительно подобного рода сайтов и по тому имеются ли у них какие-либо планы, решающие эту проблему. Если что ответят - вынесу в пост

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, кстати гляньте вопрос https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8174/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5 . Мне говорили - это к Вам)

Comment: *В частности помню(могу ошибаться), что какие-то вопросы раньше, если на них не отвечают в течении какого-бы то ни было длительного времени(например год) то ли закрывались, то ли удалялись Духом Сообщества* - все причины здесь https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/307712

Comment: @Alex Или на русском языке: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2293/

Answer (score 3):

Моё мнение такое, что если в русском интернете нет русскоязычного ответа на вопрос, то то что поисковики сверху выдают сайты с автопереводами это логично, это сделано по правилам интернета и поисковиков.

Я вижу тут два решения.

1. Это сделать свой автоперевод. Но это грязные методы... я бы такое не стал делать уподобляясь тем кто такие методы использует.
2. Изменить политику конфиденциальности, копирования, лицензии SO добавить пункты про автоперевод. В результате чего можно будет пожаловаться на такие сайты и запретить их.

Кроме того, само решение должно зависеть от задачи, а задача не очень ясна.

1. Реально SO много теряет при этом? Ведь на Сайтах с автопереводом люди не задерживаются, так как сайты не адекватны, на них нельзя спрашивать и сам перевод корявый.

Чтобы оценить реальность убытков должна быть статистика, необходимо провести реальное исследование.

Возможно опасность этих сайтов сильно завышена?

2. Либо вас интересует не доход RU SO, а польза пользователям?

С этой позиции, честно говоря, не вижу проблем, так как если человек найдёт ответ на qaru, то значит он нашёл ответ и это уже хорошо. Если ответ его не устроил, он продолжит поиск и высоковероятно в результате зайдёт на RU SO или другой SO.

PS: И да, если вы хотите повышать количество заходов в русскоязычном интернет то надо:

Делать платформу более привлекательной для людей.

Людей интересуют не только качественные вопросы и ответы, но и дружелюбная атмосфера, возможность пообщаться.

Провести анализ тех кто ушёл с SO, узнать почему. Думаю email-ы их остались в базе, и легко можно провести выборочный опрос.

PS2: я думаю эти сайты сами не выживут в долгой перспективе, так как то что делается качественно и с любовью, оно живёт долго и даже вечно. А халтура со временем отмирает. Просто делайте SO качественно и с Любовью. А другие сайты уйдут туда где им место.

Кроме того, выдача поисковиков — это их прерогатива, и они стараются делать её наиболее адекватной, поэтому почему бы просто не обратиться к ним напрямую и не обсудить эти вопросы? Я думаю что сайт SO достаточно объёмный чтобы можно 
было обратиться даже с личным визитом в Yandex и Google для обсуждения этих вопросов и для нахождения совместных решений этой ситуации.

Думаю, со временем этот вопрос решится на уровне поисковиков.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Несколько комментариев. «*если в русском интернете нет русскоязычного ответа на вопрос, то то что поисковики сверху выдают сайты с автопереводами это логично*» — не соглашусь. К пример, в нулевые, практически по любому запросу в поиск просачивалась чернуха, так как достаточно было указать нужные слова в описании странички и поисковик считал ее релевантной. Похоже что автопереводы для поисковиков — новинка, так как ранее не было, ни бесплатных API переводчиков для больших текстов, ни таких огромных баз знаний с открытой лицензией.

Comment: В автопереводах я вижу много проблем. Например: (1) Перевод ужасен, его невозможно читать. Разобраться в предмете по ним невозможно, а если бы было можно, то книги давно бы переводили алгоритмами, а не издательствами. (2) Сила Stack Overflow в сообществе. Мы приходим на сайт и видим других, таких же как мы, увлеченных профессией. Вместе мы двигаем индустрию вперед. Автопереводы убивают сообщество, позади переводов не реальная экспертиза наших коллег, а алгоритм. Когда мы сами создаем знания, мы создаем (и передаем другим) нашу культуру. Настоящую культуру, а не карикатуру на нее.

Answer (score 2):

Речь идет не просто о скопированном содержимом, а о клонировании всего stackoverflow и дальнейшем автоматическом некачественном переводе.

Данные сайты нарушают пару [рекомендаций google по обеспечению качества <strike>сайтов</strike>](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769):

> **Рекомендации:**
>
> Не используйте следующие методы:
>
> Автоматически сгенерированное содержание
>
> Публикация страниц с некачественным или скопированным контентом

[Проблемы, которые вынуждают сотрудников Google принимать определенные меры, и способы устранения этих проблем.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175)

**Вариант 1:** [пожаловаться в google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport)

На мой взгляд, руководству stakoverflow необходимо напрямую в офис google с целью обсуждения сложившейся проблемы и возможности принятия ограничительных мер, т.к. "проблема" более глобальна и касается не только отдельного раздела so, а во-вторых, на мой взгляд, так проблема будет решена более быстро, чем обращение через форму.

UPD: как минимум ограничительной мерой может быть понижение в поисковой выдаче.

---

**Вариант 2:** изменить лицензионное соглашение и добавить в него пункт о том, что содержимое сайта на котором используется содержимое SO не может состоять из более чем N% оригинальных или переведенных вопросов и ответов или что перевод должен быть качественным, с полным соблюдением правил языка, на который они переводятся.

Comment: Вариант #2 мне кажется нереализуемым. Считать % легко, но только если известны параметры, формально для этого нужно провести анализ **всего содержимого** сайта и выполнить сопоставление, и делать это с достаточной периодичностью. Вряд ли поисковикам это надо, да и на самом SO не будут тратить на это ресурсы.

Comment: По поводу перевода с полным соблюдением правил — это вовсе фантастика, даже зная правила в достаточном объёме невозможно знать их **полностью**, если вы не какой-нибудь лингвист с мировой известностью. Допустил опечатку — всё, перевод не соответствует, бан! И снова, кто будет обеспечивать эти проверки?

Comment: Большое спасибо за отзыв! Крайне интересные статьи!

Comment: @älёxölüt я и не говорю, что это идеальные решения. Обычная выборочная проверка может показать **качество перевода** и насколько сайт предположительно состоит из контента SO. Да, для этого нужны ресурсы, **вопрос в значимости**, - если такие сайты наносят или будут наносить вред SO (в т.ч. финансовый), то с этим нужно будет то-то делать рано или поздно. **По поводу соблюдения правил языка** - речь идет больше о недопустимости машинного перевода, т.е. можно смягчить правило в разумных пределах. Вряд ли кто-то будет переводить 17 млн вопросов из en.so вручную :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Переводы и Stack Overflow на русском

Уникальная ценность Stack Overflow — сообщество взаимной помощи. Без сообщества содержимое мертво, а новые вопросы никогда не получат ответ. Stack Overflow — это уникальный опыт и знания реальных людей. Знания, которые невероятно востребованы среди наших русскоязычных коллег.

> С 1 января SOen посетило 2.6 млн человек с русским языком в обозревателе. За этот же период SOru посетило 2.4 млн человек.

Автопереводы — это сгенерированный алгоритмом набор слов, зачастую полностью меняющий смысл исходного текста. С другой стороны, мы живем в мультиязычном мире. Перевод с одного языка на другие — естественный полезный процесс. Проблема не в переводах в общем, а в том как они сейчас реализованы: в виде спам–подобных текстов, которые лезет отовсюду.

Хочется верить, что мы вместе найдем куда более лаконичное решение, чем имеющееся. *Пожалуйста, поделитесь вашими идеями на этот счет!*

#### Автопереводы и наша культура

Раньше, когда я рассказывал коллегам про наше русскоязычное сообщество, частенько в ответ получал скептицизм, который заканчивался «[анекдотом про русскоязычные формуы](https://www.anekdot.ru/id/387600/)». Коллеги отказывались верить, что в русскоязычном интернете можно получить квалифицированный ответ по программированию не чувствуя себя при этом плохо.

Я рад, что у нас получилось создать сообщество неравнодушных людей, в котором комфортно каждому увлеченному программированием. Я убежден, что основные составляющие культуры русскоязычного сообщества — это доброта, отзывчивость и высокая квалификация.

Автопереводы убивают сообщество как таковое, так как люди в этом подходе не имеют никакой ценности. Вместе с сообществом умрет и культура, которую мы вместе так долго строили.

#### Что делать с автопереводами?

> Stack Overflow создается программистами, для программистов с конечной целью коллективно увеличить количество *хороших* знаний по программированию в мире.

<sub>[Из блога Джеффа Атвуда о запуске Stack Overflow.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/)</sub>

На мой взгляд, *не следует* смотреть в сторону SEO–оптимизации. Пытаться сравняться по количеству информации в нашей базе знаний и в сгенерированной базе данных также вряд ли имеет смысл, как минимум потому, что сгенерировать алгоритмом еще текста ничего не стоит. Создавать же реальные знания крайне сложно.

На мой взгляд, нам стоит сосредоточиться на качестве создаваемых знаний, а также на людях, самом сообществе. В этом деле нужна помощь каждого:

1. *Вовлекайте коллег в сообществе.* Отправьте коллегам ссылку на сайт, предложите задать вопрос по программированию сейчас или в будущем, объясните как работает сайт. Расскажите им о [миссии проекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto), культуре (например, о [нормах поведения на сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct)). Уверен, ваши личные рекомендации — единственный способ показать, что русскоязычное сообщество — это не автопереводы, а настоящие люди, энтузиасты и знатоки программирования.
2. *Создавайте больше интересного хорошего содержимого по программированию*, именно знания притягивают к нам людей. Документируйте ваш рабочий процесс заметками формата «вопрос с ответом». К слову, два самых популярных по количеству просмотров вопроса — заметки формата «вопрос с ответом» ([первый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/261/6), [второй](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/6)).
3. *Предлагайте улучшения инфраструктуры для международных сообществ.* В движок SE можно добавить много улучшений для того, чтобы сделать жизнь международным сообществам приятнее. Окружение меняется так быстро, что «можно» следует заменить на «нужно». Пожалуйста, предлагайте улучшения движка на нашей [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) или [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) ([подробнее](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315311/)). Только вместе мы сможем создать инструмент, который нас устраивает.

#### Пример улучшений: организация русскоязычной Википедии.

Размер [Википедии](https://www.wikipedia.org/) на русском языке воодушевляет: 1,5 миллиона статей на русском языке к 5,7 миллионам на английском. Для сравнения, соотношение на Stack Overflow: 240 тысяч вопросов на русском к 16,787 миллионам вопросов на английском. Очень интересно подумать, почему так происходит. Мне в глаза бросились два явных фактора (уверен, их куда больше).

1. В большинстве случаев знатоки на Stack Overflow ждут появления вопроса и лишь затем пишут к нему ответ. На Википедии заметку пишут сразу, когда хотят поделиться, не ожидая, когда кто–то, кто ищет подобные знания, «оставит заявку на написание статьи».
2. На Википедии есть [страница сообщества](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE), где указано все, с чем можно помочь проекту. На Stack Overflow эта страница реализована куда более скромно — в виде очередей проверки для участников, и очереди тревог для модераторов.

Интересно, что содержимое страницы русскоязычного сообщества Википедии отличается от аналогичной страницы (у нас же все одинаково). К примеру, на странице на русском есть инициативы связанные с переводом.

Как мне кажется, нам также можно создать страницу «сообщества», например, в справочном центре со ссылками на Мету, которая будет рассказывать про устройство нашего сообщества и содержать список актуальных задач. А также попробовать и другие инициативы, подобные тем, что есть на Википедии. Например, попробовать вместе покрывать определенные области каноническими вопросами в заданный промежуток времени.

Буду крайне рад услышать ваш отзыв и любые предложения по теме вопроса!

Comment: "Очень интересно подумать, почему так происходит" Потому что программисты в большинстве своём умеют в английский, а пользователи Википедии нет.

Comment: Вы очень сильно передергиваете, и непонятно зачем. Отсутствие ценности в автопереводах это ложная предпосылка. Автоперевод лучше чем никакого перевода вовсе.

Comment: Кстати в тему про Википедию, которую вы ставите в пример, взгляните - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsjbot это бот который вывел Шведскую вики на 2е место, нагенерив в сумме с другими ботами более миллиона статей. Так что количеству статей там тоже нельзя доверять просто так. Многие из них автосгенерированы.

Comment: @Kromster Подскажите, пожалуйста, значит ли это, что вы бы хотели видеть автопереводы у нас на сайте?

Comment: Это значит, что я считаю, что в ответе идет сильное передергивание и тем самым заметно дискредитируется общая точка зрения описываемая ниже. Отсылка к Вики так же несколько неудачный пример.

Comment: @Kromster Пожалуйста, раскройте вашу точку зрения отдельным ответом.

Comment: У меня нет ответа существенно отличающегося от уже размещенных (проголосовал за некоторые из них).

Comment: @Kromster На всякий случай поясню, чтобы не возникло недопонимания. Я разделяю мнение многих высказавшихся в этой теме, что автопереводы в текущем виде вызывают фрустрацию, особенно когда они везде. Можно ли сделать лучше? Конечно! Вопрос в том, как? Я буду рад выслушать мнение всех заинтересованных участников. Спасибо за ссылку на вики–бота. Интересный опыт.

Comment: @Kromster В тоже время, я в корне не согласен с «Автоперевод лучше чем никакого перевода вовсе». Это звучит как «вам шашечки или ехать?» В ИТ мире в 99% нужны именно «шашечки», потому что мы решаем инфраструктурную задачу. Если фундамент возвести не верно или абы как, в доме будет жить, как минимум, не безопасно.

Comment: К сожалению не могу понять второй комментарий. Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Kromster Представьте, что вам достался сломанный нерабочий автомобиль, который занимает все место в гараже. Его никак не исправить, а выкинуть не получается, потому что кто–то вам его подарил «от всего сердца». Стоит и место занимает, это использовать нельзя (а еще надо налоги платить!) Замечу, что без такого авто жизнь была бы куда радостней.  Автоперевод не лучше, чем никакого. Хороший, качественно выполненный перевод лучше, чем его отсутствие.

Comment: Данный пример некорректен. Сломанный автомобиль (автопереводы) у нас места не занимает, налогов не требует. Скорее был бы верен пример, что у нас тут салон по продаже качественных авто 240 марок, новых и бу (оригинальные и вручную переведенные вопросы), но расположен он не на МКАД/КАД, а вдалеке от города (плохое SEO), а перед ним площадки на которых продают авто с неизвестной историей (автопереводы), но в гораздо большем ассортименте. И покупателю, чтобы добраться до нас, надо через эти площадки продраться и существенно ограничить себя в выборе. Вот и вопрос ..

Comment: .. что нам делать, начинать самим торговать рухлядью (автопереводами) и тем самым вытеснить другие площадки, или придвинуться поближе к городу (SEO наладить), или декоративную 15см елочку в уголке покупателя поставить (создать страницу «сообщества» в справочном центре)

Comment: @Kromster Я вижу проблему в том, что есть только одна первая, вторая и третья строчка в поисковой выдачи. И там либо качественное содержимое, либо его там нет.

Answer (score 0):

1. Поправить движок и его SEO часть, чтобы поисковики нормально воспринимали контент.
2. Прекратить блочить предложения на Area51, касающиеся локализованных сайтов.
3. Вместо какой-то автоматизированной системы, которая будет, очевидно, криво работать, нужно **поощрять авторов** за ручные переводы вопросов с SOen.

Comment: *"нужно поощрять авторов"* - уточните, чем их дополнительно поощрять помимо и так практически гарантированной репы за переведенный вопрос и ответ?

Comment: @Kromster вот чего не знаю, того не знаю. Но лично для меня с моим уровнем репутация уже почти ничего не значит =/

Comment: Вот для меня так же, репа не мотиватор, поэтому в своем ответе сделал упор на юзабельнось. Что кроме репы стоит задействовать?

Comment: @Kromster может отдельный блок справа (там где "важное") со списком новых переводов? Надо подумать.

Answer (score -2):

Проблема, конечно же, не в эпигонах - их у любых успешных проектов всегда тыщи. А в том, что они располагаются выше в поисковой выдаче, чем ссылки на оригинальный контент.

И проблема эта будет усугубляться, благодаря шизофренической натуре сайтов системы Stack Overflow, которые одной рукой ну оооооочень хотят быть светиться на первых строчках в гугле, но другой принципиально ориентированы на ублажение автора исходного вопроса, пусть даже он задал его 10 лет назад и никогда больше не интересовался его судьбой.

Для того, чтобы сайт представлял интерес для поисковиков, на нем надо культивировать контент. Концентрироваться на создании качественных ответов и создании ссылочной массы на них. Тогда, видя интерес пользователей к определённому ответу, поисковики будут поднимать его в выдаче. Это азы СЕО.

Но на Stack Overflow всем на них плевать. Здесь пупом земли является автор вопроса, вокруг которого положено бегать на цырлах. И не дай бог тронуть исходный вопрос, пусть он даже была задан 5 лет назад и с тех пор автор даже на сайт ни разу не заходил. Фигура автора священна. И поэтому сайт представляет из себя жидкую размазню  из десятков тысяч торопливых ответов на бессмысленные вопросы, а не собрание хорошо проработанных ответов, каким он задумывался. В итоге человек, у которого проблема с Экселем, читает ответ про то, как управлять памятью. И уходит за информацией к конкурентам.

Я, конечно, партизаню, и стараюсь иногда исправлять особо одиозные случаи, типа [такого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/336359/revisions), но местные вахтёры не дремлют, и если видят правку, которая - ах, какой скандаль! - меняет исходный вопрос на нечто осмысленное, то тут же откатывают её.

С таким подходом только и остаётся, что плакаться о нечестной конкуренции, да.