# Как настроить гугл, чтобы исключить из поиска сайт (граббер) qaru.site?

Tags: поддержка, stackoverflow

Ужасный сайт, который выдает машинный перевод ответов со Stack Overflow. Мне нужно, чтобы гугл не выдавал его в ответах, лучше вместо него англоязычная версия Stack Overflow. Как его убрать из выдачи?

Вообще не понимаю смысл данного сайта, кроме как заработок авторов на рекламе, с воздуха разумеется.

Нельзя ли как-то подать жалобу в поисковике на ресурсы такого плана? Это вообще законно? Давайте сейчас для каждого сайта сделаем по 100 оболочек с редиректами и будем вставлять рекламу на каждую страницу?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Автоперевод содержимого Stack Overflow. Что вы об этом думаете?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8267/176217)

Comment: Для людей, которые на русском ищут: а гугл умеет по русским ключевым словам ссылки на вопросы с английского Stack Overflow выводить? Если результаты только на английском нужны, то в настройках поиска разрешённые языки можно поправить.

Comment: Увы, это законно

Comment: Кстати, qaru скоро станет настоящим форумом. Так что можете не убирать.

Comment: @VerNick вот только зачем, если уже имеется сотня аналогов, чем toster не устраивает? нагребли трафика за счет другого сайта, и делают полноценный вопросник? имхо, это ужасно

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/457714/#comment_20335968 пример с userscript

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Вариант 1**: в конце запроса добавлять: `" -site:qaru.site"`.

Пример:

```
мой вопрос о чём-либо -site:qaru.site
```

**Вариант 2:** использовать расширения для браузеров, например такое: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklistnot-by/cbbbhelcpfjhdcncigdlkabmjbgokmpg - по кнопке "импортировать" в этом расширении можно задать, какие сайты убирать из поисковой выдачи. upd: Периодически не работает. Ещё один вариант: uBlacklist (можно легко найти в маркете хрома)

---

И обратный вариант, если нужно искать только на [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com), то запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
мой вопрос о чём-либо site:stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Второй вариант не работает.

Comment: На момент написания ответа - работало. Видимо, гугл что-то поменял у себя. Можно использовать, например uBlacklist

Comment: @XelaNimed, отлично работает, только `ru.` добавь.

Comment: @Qwertiy ещё раз проверил (добавлены qaru.site, qaru.ru) - не работает.

Comment: @XelaNimed, значит проверяй пока не заработает. У всех всё работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAh2L.png Пробел после двоеточия удали, если ты его там поставил. И раскладку проверь, напечатай весь запрос полностью без опечаток.

Comment: @Qwertiy не работает ВТОРОЙ вариант с расширением: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef

Comment: @XelaNimed, а я думал, второй это с поиском по сайту. Про расширение не в курсе.

Answer (score 17):

Для блокировщиков рекламы (adblock, uBlock) можно прописать отдельный фильтр.

Добавить строчку:

```
google.com,google.by,google.com.ua,google.kz,google.ru#?##search .srg > .g:-abp-has(a[href*="qaru.site"])
```

Результат без фильтра:
[image: Без фильтра]

С фильтром:
[image: С фильтром]

За решение спасибо liamarwi с хабра.

Comment: О... с фильтром даже поиск на 4 сотых секунды быстрее :)

Comment: В последнее время указанный фильтр перестал работать. Сейчас работает вариант с google.*##.g:has(a[href*="qaru.site"])

Answer (score 9):

На примере Google Chrome (в других браузерах наверняка имеются аналогичные настройки).
В настройках проходим в управление поисковыми системами: `chrome://settings/searchEngines`, нажимаем кнопку `Добавить` и в текстовом поле URL вводим:

`{google:baseURL}search?q=%s+-site%3Aqaru.site`

и устанавливаем созданную поисковую систему по-умолчанию. После этого ко всем поисковым запросам, введённым в адресную строку, будет автоматически добавляться исключение сайта из поисковой выдачи.

Для исключения нескольких доменов необходимо дублировать `-site:`

`{google:baseURL}search?q=%s+-site%3Aqaru.site+-site%3Atoster.ru`

Answer (score 6):

> Как настроить гугл, чтобы исключить из поиска сайт (граббер) qaru.site?

Можно сменить регион в настройках поиска:
https://www.google.com/preferences --> Region Settings -->  United States.

По умолчанию в настройках стоит "Current Region". Я так понимаю что когда стоит "Current Region", гугл считает меня русскоязычным пользователем и предлагает больше сайтов на русском языке. Если поставить "United States", то qaru.site вроде бы исчезает из выдачи гугла.

Comment: Вы предлагаете каждый раз переключать эту настройку? Ведь помимо qaru "отвалятся" и другие...

Comment: Нет, оставить постоянно. При этом в гугле искать по англоязычному интернету, а в яндексе по русскоязычному. Я в общем и раньше всегда так делал.

Comment: На мой взгляд такое "решение", как минимум, не удобно.

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант, перенаправляться на [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) при заходе на этот сайт.

Исключать его из поиска не лучший вариант.
Дополнительная индексация как таковая вреда не несёт. Это даже хорошо, появляется больше шансов найти ответ.

Вот UserScript с таким функционалом:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Redirecting from qaru.site to stackoverflow.com
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.2
// @author       vp_arth (habr.com/ru/users/vp_arth/, ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176064/vp-arth)
// @match        http://qaru.site/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    location.replace(document.querySelector('.question-text .aa-link').href)
})();
```

За скрипт спасибо участнику ***vp_arth***. Он был опубликован в [комментарии](https://habr.com/ru/post/457714/#comment_20335968) к статье на хабре.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте JS-расширение для браузера, которое будет редиректить вас на оригинальную страницу ответа.

https://github.com/Taraflex/Back2stackoverflow