# Не работает сортировка ответов на Мете

Tags: дефект, мета

Может у меня что-то с руками, но не могу отсортировать ответы на Мете. На основном все корректно работает

Сортировка от старых к новым

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в обратном порядке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никаких изменений. Всегда показывается самый старый ответ с начала.

Потестил на двух вопросах

[Первый](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8364/209304)
[Второй](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/209304)

UPD пример по первой ссылке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по первой ссылке - все правильно сортирует

Comment: @Grundy добавил принтскрины с результатом

Comment: Плохой скриншот. На хорошем должно быть два вопроса - чтобы можно было сравнить даты создания/изменения и увидеть что действительно ошибка. Но конкретно в случае первого вопроса - ошибок нет

Comment: Кроме того, судя по всему на мете все еще действует прибитие ответа с галочкой в верху. Остальные ответы сортируются согласно выбранному условию

Comment: @Grundy точно, сортирует все что ниже принятого ответа. Это меня сбило

Comment: Обрати внимание, что по первой ссылке, даже если бы не было галочки у ответа - он бы все равно занимал это же место.